# Rails control Job execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs

I have a job created with `rails g job cleanUp`.

Is where any option to check if Job is running? Something like this `CleanUpJob.isRunning?`

If where is no way to make it without additional gems, which will be the simplest? delayed_job?

Second thing to control Job is progress, any thoughts how to implement `CleanUpJob.progress` or progress_job should be my choice?

briefly:

I need to create a job with two methods (isRunning?, progress).
I don't really want additional tables if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Class: Sidekiq::ScheduledSet` for this purpose.

Documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/ScheduledSet)
This Class is used in Sidekiq web interface.

Example:
 Save job id (jid) when set job. Then you can call it for queried instance

```
def is_running? 
  require 'sidekiq/api'
  ss = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
  jobs = ss.select {|ret| ret.jid == self.jid}
  jobs.any?
end
```

Or, you can set DB flag inside Job with `around_perform` hook.

```
 class SomeJob < ActiveJob::Base
      queue_as :some_job

      around_perform do |job, block|
        start_import_process_log job.arguments[0], job.arguments[1] || {}
        block.call
        finish_import_process_log
      end

 #   ...
    private

  def start_import_process_log import_process, options={}
    #some actions
  end

  def finish_import_process_log
  end

 end
```

In this example associated log record is created.
Or you can use before_perform/ after_perform.

In my practice I'm using creting log records on long tasks.

When I need to find and kill job as example - I'm using `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet`.